# Object initializers and With keyword

Tags: vb.net

In reference to VB.Net and not to be confused with; With/End With (I think?)

```
Dim cust0 As Customer = New Customer With {.Name = "Toni Poe", 
                                           .City = "Louisville"}
```

[Object Initializers: Named and Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx)

Question: I cannot find any direct reference to the use of **With** in the above context. I understand how it is used but cannot find any documentation on MSDN about its use, other than from the link I've included, and even there it's not specifically referenced or explained.

There may be no more there there...? And while I'm pretty sure it's not related to the more dated With/End With usage, I'd just like to find a more detailed description of it's use. Anyone? Thanks.

Comment: I'd say it's a one-liner of `With/End With`.

Comment: [How to: Declare an Object by Using an Object Initializer (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531244.aspx)

Comment: @VisualVincent: I don't see how you think it's a "one-liner of With/End With".  These are not related at all.  The With/End With allows accessing members of an object within a block without specifying the object, while the newer usage of With is solely for instantiating named or anonymous types.  You see a link between these?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas : Because you still access members without specifying the name of the object? It behaves the same just at different times, but I guess only the IL can tell wether they're is different or not.

Comment: Even though `With {}` have the capability of setting properties of anonymous types, it still behaves a lot like `With/End With`.

Answer (score 1):

So I did find this, reference to **With** as a *keyword* versus statement. So they are different creatures, though kind of sort of related. There doesn't appear to be an entry in MSDN specifically for **With** as keyword.

[With...End With Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)

> You can use the With keyword in object initializers also. For more
>   information and examples, see Object Initializers: Named and Anonymous
>   Types (Visual Basic) and Anonymous Types (Visual Basic).

Comment: I saw that too. \*ahem\* one-liner \*ahem\* :)

Comment: Well you didn't propose it as an answer :P

Comment: I know. But I implied that I think that `With/End With` actually is the same as `With {}`. You say that _"they are different creatures"_, but I think they actually are the same. It's like `If ... Then/End If` and `If ... Then`.

Comment: And I've marked your responses as helpful. I apologize if it seemed I've not considered your contribution. Thank you.

Comment: Wow, I guess I should go to bed now. You're the second one tonight that think I'm mad or irritated due to how I express my comments. :)

Comment: You don't have to apologize for anything. I _did not_ think that you hadn't considered my comments. Well then, good night. :)